# two onchange function based on single dropdown, but each onchange has different condition , trigger onchange based on what function you called

Tags: javascript, jquery, web, web-applications

Two function have an `onchange` event based on single dropdown but that
`onchange` event has different condition on each function, when I call
function `fun1` it triggers `onchange` what I mentioned in `fun1`, but when I
call `fun2` it triggers both `onchange`. How to restrict it?

**HTML**

```
 <select id='number'>
      <option>1</option>
      <option>2</option>
      <option>3</option>
 </select>
```

**jquery**

```js
function fun1() {
  $('#number').on('change', function() {
    var val = this.value;
    if(val > 2){
      console.log('hello first function');
    }
  });
}

function fun2() {
  $('#number').on('change', function() {
    var val = this.value;
    if(val < 2){
      console.log('hello second function');
    }
  });
}
```

When I called `fun1` my output = `'hello first function'`.  When I called `fun2` my output = `'hello second function'`. When I again call my `fun1` my output = `'hello first function'` `'hello second function'`, but I need my output like `this='hello first function'`.

Comment: did you tried `one` function? `$('#number').one('change', ...)` use this in both function

Answer (score 0):

I think you could do it this way, by overriding a function variable:

```js
// default function, do nothing
let delegate = () => {};

// assign the delegate to fun1's onchange content
function fun1() {
  delegate = () => {
    var val = this.value;

    if(val > 2){
      console.log('hello first function');
    }
  }
}

// assign the delegate to fun2's onchange content
function fun2() {
  delegate = () => {
    var val = this.value;

    if(val < 2){
      console.log('hello second function');
    }
  }
}

$('#number').on('change', function() {
  delegate();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

The reason why it is not working is: The `$('#number').on('change', function() {...})` is itself a function, it doesn't need to get wrapped inside a function that is getting executed only once... And hence it is not working properly...

By the way you can do this in very short way without needing extra functions :

```
$("#number").on("change", function() {
        let val = this.value
        if(val > 2){
            console.log("hello first function")
            //you can execute your first function here
            //or you can write whatever your first function does here
        }
        else{
            console.log('hello second function');
            //same goes here
        }
    })
```

This is very optimized way to do what you want...

Comment: Thank You , for your answer aditya panchal